# Parsing txt file into Excel with multiple delimiters

Tags: excel, vba, parsing

Is there a way to parse lines of data from a .txt file using multiple delimitters?  Specifically, I'm importing a .txt file using VBA and QueryTables and the .TextFileOtherDelimiter method.  But my file has different delimitters (ex: ":" & "=") that I want to be able separate in one passing.

Also, is there a way to parse the data using more than one character such as ".-" or ":(tab)"?

I'm iterating through a bunch of files in multiple directories.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
For Each File In Folder.Files
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" _
          & File, Destination:=Range("A1"))
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = DataStartRow
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = True
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileOtherDelimiter = TestDataDelimiter
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
next
```

So can my TestDataDelimiter be something besides a single char?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the file in line-by-line.  Then convert the multiple delimiters into a single delimiter by using **Replace()**.  Then use **Split()** on the common delimiter.

**EDIT#1:**

Here is some sample code to illustrate.  Say we want to parse using both **+** and **-**

with data like:

```
hello+world-goodby+for-now
12+34+qwerty-poiunyt
```

This macro:

```
Sub ParseData()
    Dim FileSpec As String, TextLine As String
    Dim RowNumber As Long
    folder = "C:\TestFolder\textfiles"
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fso.GetFolder(folder)
    RowNumber = 1
    Close #1

    For Each file In folder.Files
        FileSpec = folder & "\" & file.Name
        Open FileSpec For Input As #1
        Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            TextLine = Replace(TextLine, "+", "-")
            If InStr(TextLine, "-") = 0 Then
                Cells(RowNumber, 1) = TextLine
            Else
                ary = Split(TextLine, "-")
                ccol = 1
                For Each a In ary
                    Cells(RowNumber, ccol) = a
                    ccol = ccol + 1
                Next a
            End If
            RowNumber = RowNumber + 1
        Loop
        Close #1
    Next file
End Sub
```

will produce:

[image]

Comment: I added my code to the question.  How would this work with what I have?  I don't think I have access to each line as it comes in, so I'm not sure how I would manipulate that portion of it.

Comment: @KingKong  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Oh, I didn't know about some of these functions.  Appreciate you showing me some new VBA features.  This does seem to work though. Thanks!